# To show the syntax of created table

Tags: sql, oracle

i  am trying to show the syntax of a created  table as described below
here is the  sturucture of the table:

[image: sql>desc student;]

i need the  complete syntax of  table creation as:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (R_NUMBER NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,F_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, M_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, ADMN_NO REFERENCES FEE NUMBER(4);
```

Is there any data dictionary through which I can get this output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can query data dictionary views `user_tab_columns` and `user_cons_columns` joined :

```
select c.column_name, c.data_type, c.nullable, s.constraint_name, c.data_length
  from user_tab_columns c , user_cons_columns s 
 where c.table_name = 'AB'
   and s.column_name(+) = c.column_name
   and s.table_name(+) = c.table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` using something like

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'STUDENT', 'MYSCHEMA') -- Replace MYSCHEMA with your actual schema name
FROM dual
```